# powershell add a group to all spo sites but authentication error

Tags: powershell, pnp-powershell

I am receiving authentication error. I have pim and access to admin center. any idea? I figured it out. my privilege access expired. it's working now.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.